# What is wrong with my SHA256 hash function?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, hash, sha

I am writing this function in a Windows application that  generates a SHA-256 hash of some text. The code compiles and runs fine, but seems to produce incorrect output.

```
char GSalt[17] = { 0 };

HRESULT SaltHashAndStorePassword(_In_ char* PlainTextPassword)
{
    HCRYPTPROV CryptProvider = NULL;
    HCRYPTHASH HashPointer = NULL;

    char PlainTextPasswordWithSalt[64] = { 0 };

    strcat_s(PlainTextPasswordWithSalt, PlainTextPassword);
    strcat_s(PlainTextPasswordWithSalt, GSalt); 

    if (CryptAcquireContext(&CryptProvider, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT) == FALSE)
    {
        return(E_FAIL);
    }

    if (CryptCreateHash(CryptProvider, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, &HashPointer) == FALSE)
    {
        CryptReleaseContext(CryptProvider, 0);
        return(E_FAIL);
    }

    if (CryptHashData(HashPointer, (BYTE*)PlainTextPasswordWithSalt, (DWORD)strlen(PlainTextPasswordWithSalt), 0) == FALSE)
    {
        CryptDestroyHash(HashPointer);
        CryptReleaseContext(CryptProvider, 0);
        return(E_FAIL);
    }

    BYTE HashBytes[32] = { 0 };
    DWORD HashSize = 32;

    if (CryptGetHashParam(HashPointer, HP_HASHVAL, HashBytes, &HashSize, 0) == FALSE)
    {
        CryptDestroyHash(HashPointer);
        CryptReleaseContext(CryptProvider, 0);
        return(E_FAIL);
    }

    char *Hex = "0123456789abcdef";
    char HashString[65] = { 0 };

    for (int Count = 0; Count < 32; Count++)
    {
        HashString[Count * 2] = Hex[HashBytes[Count] >> 4];
        HashString[(Count * 2) + 1] = Hex[HashBytes[Count] & 0xF];
    }

    CryptDestroyHash(HashPointer);
    CryptReleaseContext(CryptProvider, 0);

    return(S_OK);
}
```

Here is a screenshot from a Visual Studio debugging session, showing the current variable values while this function is being run.

[image: values]

So as you can see, I am attempting to generate a SHA-256 hash of the text

`food@Jt/+iI?{?n\\}L(`

But the resulting hash comes out as

`7804d488ccc172d87314474fb7f9951ec554cac33232bf2efc081afd323ca563`

Which isn't correct based on the other SHA256 calculators I've tested with.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me. `echo -n 'food@Jt/+iI?{?n\\}L(' | sha256sum` -> `7804d488ccc172d87314474fb7f9951ec554cac33232bf2efc081afd323ca563`

Comment: All the sha256 calculators I've used say the hash is `F33698F7E297979EE47D4C3D1C18BA3CCDA598C054019868DDEA5E0EE86831FE`

Comment: @immibis: I copy and pasted your command and I get `f33...` same as Ryan.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ah.  The `780...` result is what you get if you only have a single backslash instead of two backslashes.  @immibis, any chance your shell is compressing the two backslashes into one?  (Or perhaps my shell is suppressing the single backslash somehow?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston That was it! Thank you for the clue. The Visual Studio debugger was tricking me by putting that escape character in there. The hash actually is correct afterall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just checked, and the Visual Studio 2013 debugger shows single backslashes as double backslashes in character strings.  (Visual Studio 2010 does not.)

So the string you are actually hashing is

```
food@Jt/+iI?{?n\}L(
```

for which the result you are getting is correct.